# torch.return_types.max as Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I try to pass `torch.max()` return type (`torch.return_types.max`) as argument to function `torch.tile()`:

`torch.tile(torch.max(x), (1, 1, 1, 5))`

The error is: `TypeError: tile(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not torch.return_types.max`.

How can I convert `torch.return_types.max` to `Tensor`? Maybe I should use another function to find maximum in Tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this error to be true, you have to be using some `dim=?`, because only then [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html) will return a tuple of `(values, indices)`.

You can fix that error by using only the first output:

```py
torch.tile(torch.max(x, dim=0)[0], (1, 1, 1, 5))
```